# JQuery if else statement with percentage

Tags: jquery

So here is my code:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    if ( $('li').width() == '7%' ) {
        $('li').animate({
            width: '86%'
        },300);
    } else {
        $('li').animate({
            width: '7%'
        },300);
    }
});
```

The percentage seem no work. If i change it to pixel, it totally, but in percentage, it seem like got error.

Any professional can help me out of this? Please!

==================================================================================

Okay now I change it to css:

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    if ( $('li').css('width') == '70px' ) {
        $('li').animate({
            width: '86%'
        },300);
    } else {
        $('li').animate({
            width: '70px'
        },300);
    }
});
```

but when i change 70px to 7%, it's no work. why?

Comment: It doesn't work because as I said in my answer, `width()` returns a **float** not a string! You need `== 70` not `== '70px'`, since that statement will never be true.

Answer (score 5):

.width() returns a number, not a string, so you have to calculate the percentage yourself!

Comment: I would recommend to have a boolean which tells if you are in narrow mode or not, toggle that boolean to get the desired functionality

Answer (score 0):

Percentages are converted to pixels by the browser, so any calls to width will return an integer value of pixels.

Get the container width and multiply by 0.07 and compare against this instead.

Comment: But as @Andres pointed out in a comment below his answer, creating a variable which holds the state rather than relying on width would be better.

Answer (score 0):

`width()` will return the physical size of the element in pixels. You'll need to calculate its percentage width based on the width of the element's parent. Something like this might work for you:

```
var the_percentage = ($('li').width() / $('li').parent().width()) * 100;
if(the_percentage == 7)
{
    // Something here...
}
else
{
    // Something else here...
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this check instead:

```
var li = $('li');
if((li.parent().width() * 0.07) == li.width()) {
```